# Why some time jquery click event fails?

Tags: ajax, jquery

My page is divided into two parts `vertically`.`Left part` is like a menu section. Clicking on
any menu brings the proper data related to that menu in the `right part` of the page. I am
doing it using `ajax call` and the only `div on the right part` get refreshed. I am using jquery click event for that .. 
say:

```
$("#left_part").click(function() {  // ajax call here });
```

Now I have some more `jquery action` on the `right part`. (say Show hide some div which also work on `click event.`)
But when `new div reloads` on the right part those `click event on the right part` is not working.
But when I `bind the click event` it works.

say:

```
$("#some_right_part").click(function() {/ some hide show here )}; Not working
$("#some_right_part").bind('click', function(event){ // some hide show here )}; works fine
```

**Important:** When I am on `fresh page` (no ajax call yet to bring right part) `$("#some_right_part").click(function() {/ some hide show here )}; works fine.`

But what I know is:  `$().click(function)` calls `$().bind('click',function)`

So, What is the reason behind this? Or What is the perfect way to solve such problem

Thanks

Comment: This should not fail as you describe, it is probably something else. If you post your entire code chunk that is failing using `click` it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you assign a click event via `$().click` when the page loads, the click event is bound to all matching elements. However, when you do the ajax call and recieve new markup - the new elements are not bound to the click event because they did not exist when you first called `$().click`.

There is a way to get a click event to be bound to all elements and all future elements that may be created. You must use the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method like so:

```
$('#elements').live('click', function() {
   // do logic
});
```